# JSON::ParserError Exception: 757: unexpected token at 'Token scope not set. This request does not have the required privilege.'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autodesk-forge

I am integrating Autodesk with Ruby on Rails using adn_viewer gem (https://github.com/GetSomeRest/adn_viewer). While creating bucket using the following code:

```
Adn_Viewer.create_bucket(token, name, policy)
```

The function definition in adn_viewer.rb is as follows:

```
def self.create_bucket(token, name, policy)
    url = URI("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v1/buckets")
    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
    request["content-type"] = 'application/json'
    request["authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + token
    request.body = "{\"bucketKey\":\"" + name + "\",\"policy\":\"" + policy + "\"}"
    JSON.parse(http.request(request).read_body)
end
```

The error which I am getting is:

```
JSON::ParserError Exception: 757: unexpected token at 'Token scope not set. This request does not have the required privilege.'
```

Comment: it looks like your `http.request(request).read_body` is not a JSON encoded string; it is just a string. a JSON encoded string needs to decode to either an array or hash to be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample is obsolete and not maintained, nor the Ruby package that was produced last year.
We are about to release a new package and sample to match the latest state of the API which was officially release last June. In the meantime, you need to add at least the bucket:create scope for this API as document here: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/overview/scopes/ and here: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-POST/

Change the authenticate call with the appropriate scope you need. Usually data:read data:write data:update bucket:read bucket:create bucket:update

Change this line: https://github.com/GetSomeRest/adn_viewer/blob/master/lib/adn_viewer.rb#L9
with:

`JSON.parse(CurbFu.post({:host => 'developer.api.autodesk.com', :path => '/authentication/v1/authenticate', :protocol => "https"}, { :client_id => key, :client_secret => secret, :grant_type => 'client_credentials', :scope=> 'put your scopes here' }).body)`

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will check this and update you.

Comment: Hello @cyrille,

I was able to create bucket and upload files in it. But when I am trying to open the viewer and see the file in it, I am getting JS error in following file: 

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.min.js

It says:

viewer3D.min.js:4 Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'json').p @ viewer3D.min.js:4

Also, it is downloading the file before opening the viewer. Can you help in this regard.

Comment: if you could post your code somewhere for me to test, I'll be happy to give it a shot. my minimal viewer example is post there, where I push the URN and access_token as parameters in the query string. https://github.com/cyrillef/models.autodesk.io/blob/master/www/view.html